# How to access value in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: lightblue;" onClick="alert(myArray[0][1])">
this is a div
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0][0] = 0;
myArray[0][1] = 00012;
myArray[0][2] = 00006;
myArray[1][0] = 1;
myArray[1][1] = 00004;
myArray[1][2] = 00001;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the div, nothing happens; there's no alert. When I change the inside of alert to a string, such as 'test', however, then the alert box does come up.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the value of an item in a multidimensional array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your code:

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

...will create a new, *single dimensional* array, `myArray`, that has no elements. Then when you say:

```
myArray[0][0] = 0;
```

...you are trying to access a dimension that doesn't exist yet. That is, `myArray[0]` is `undefined` because although `myArray` is an array it doesn't have any elements yet - so `myArray[0][0]` is like saying `undefined[0]`.

That's why you have to to assign `myArray[0]` to refer to a new array before you can access `myArray[0][0]`. The same thing applies to `myArray[1]`, because JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays per se, it has arrays of arrays. So this is what you need (for a minimal change to your existing code):

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = [];
myArray[0][0] =  00012;
myArray[0][1] = 00012;
myArray[0][2] = 00006;
myArray[1] = [];
myArray[1][0] = 1;
myArray[1][1] = 00004;
myArray[1][2] = 00001;
```

Note that `[]` is equivalent to `new Array()`.

An easier to read and type option is to create the sub-arrays via array literal syntax:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = [00012, 00012, 00006];
myArray[1] = [1, 00004, 00001];
```

Or, easiest of all (especially if these are hard-coded values) is creating the whole thing in one statement via a nested array literal (white-space is ignored):

```
var myArray = [
                [00012, 00012, 00006],
                [1, 00004, 00001]
              ];
```

(Note also that those leading zeros will disappear for numeric data: use strings (`"00012"` instead of `00012`) if you want to retain the zeros.)

Answer (score 2):

Write it out like this:

```
<div style="background-color: lightblue;" onClick="alert(myArray[0][1])">
    this is a div
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myArray = [];
    myArray.push([0, 00012, 00006]);
    myArray.push([1, 00004, 00001]);
</script>
```

**Edit**

The problem is that when you write this:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0][0] = 0;
```

The first item in *myArray* is undefined, so you can't do anything with it.  Using this method, you'd have to create the array first:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = new Array();
myArray[0][0] = 0;
```

But I think the method of using the square notation with *push* is cleaner.

Comment: Is the way I did it incorrect? I did it that way based on what I read on this page: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/javascript-multi-dimensional-array.html

Comment: @Nate the only part you left out is creating the inner array object.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How is the first item in the array undefined? Is that because I assign it a value of zero? I'm used to programming in PHP, and I'm a little confused what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: @Nate not because you assign it zero; it's empty because *nothing* has been assigned to it yet.  Ie, if you write *var a = new Array(); alert(a[0]);* that gives you *undefined*.  So when you try to write *a[0][0]*, that's like treating *undefined* as if it were an array.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you declare a multi dimensional array:

```
MultiArray = new Array(2)

MultiArray [0] = new Array(2)

MultiArray [0][0] = "Tom"

MultiArray [0][1] = "scientist"

MultiArray [1] = new Array(2)

MultiArray [1][0] = "Beryl"

MultiArray [1][1] = "engineer"
```