# create multidimensional array by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This is a very strange to me actually. I can't figure out how create a multidimensional array dynamically. I want to create a three-level drop-down list, so I think I need a three dimensional array to store the values. How to create three dimensional array?

```
<script language=javascript>

var aCourse=new Array();
aCourse[0]=new Array();
aCourse[1]=new Array();
aCourse[2]=new Array();
aCourse[3]=new Array();

aCourse[0][0]="Select...";
aCourse[1][0]="Select...";
aCourse[1][1]="T Square";
aCourse[1][2]="V Square";
aCourse[1][3]="S Square";
aCourse[1][4]="B Square";
aCourse[1][5]="G Square";
aCourse[2][0]="Select...";
aCourse[2][1]="N Square";
aCourse[2][2]="W Square";
aCourse[3][0]="Select…";
aCourse[3][1]="J Square";
aCourse[3][2]="M Square";

function ChangeCourse()
{
var i,
iCategoryIndex;
iCategoryIndex=document.frm.optCategory.selectedIndex;
iCourseCount=0;
while (aCourse[iCategoryIndex][iCourseCount]!=null)
iCourseCount++;
document.frm.optCourse.length=iCourseCount;
for (i=0;i<=iCourseCount-1;i++)
document.frm.optCourse[i]=new Option(aCourse[iCategoryIndex][i]);
document.frm.optCourse.focus();
}

</script>
<body ONfocus=ChangeCourse()>
<h3>Choose category…</h3>
<form name="frm">
<p>Category:
<select name="optCategory" size="1" onChange=ChangeCourse()>
<option>Select…</option>
<option>Soccer</option>
<option>Cricket</option>
<option>Rugby</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>Fields
<select name="optCourse" size="1">
<option>Select…</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: The answers and discussion from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11174096/615754) should help you. JS doesn't have multidimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays - this distinction is important. By the way, the values you are assigning only seem to be in two dimensions, not three.

Comment: I know it is two dimension, that is why I asked how to make it in three. Thank you.

Comment: OK, sure. I assumed you were having trouble getting even two dimensions to work given that the code you show that assigns the values won't work as is. The principles shown in the question I linked to above and in the answers below can be extended to as many dimensions as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only problem is creating the three-dimensional array, this should work:

```
var aCourse = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dimensionOneSize; i++) {
  aCourse[i] = [];
  for(var k = 0; k < dimensionTwoSize; k++)
    aCourse[i][k] = [];
}
```

It is good to note that JavaScript supports the short-hand definition of an array with square brackets `[]`, so you can use those to make the dynamic definition cleaner.

### Possibly Shorter

Also, I'm not sure if this works very well, but it might:

```
var aCourse = [[[]]];
```

So far, my testing has not proven a way to use this, but it does validate as a proper script.

Comment: What if it is a three dimensional arrays?

Comment: `aCourse = [[[]]]` will "work" in the sense that it is valid JS after which `aCourse` is an array with one element, `aCourse[0]` contains an array with one element, and `aCourse[0][0]` contains an array with no elements. At that point `aCourse[1]` is still undefined so `aCourse[1][0]` would give an error...

Answer (score 0):

First, it's always good to initialize arrays using square brackets, `[]`:

```
var aCourse = [];
```

And to simulate multidimensional arrays in JS, which is essentially an indeterminate number of arrays inside of a single array, do this:

```
aCourse[0] = [];
```

Or you could create the arrays inside of the square brackets when creating the array:

```
var aCourse = [
    [], [], []
];
```

This is equivalent to:

```
aCourse[0] = [];
aCourse[1] = [];
aCourse[2] = [];
```