# How to use javascript to populate multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use javascript to populate multidimensional arrays.
I want to create three dropdownlists to display "name", "nationality" and "occasion". However, I only can complete a two dimensional arrays.

Any good idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you done so far?, we can start from there

Comment: Could you have a look at here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286806/create-multidimensional-array-by-using-javascript

Comment: jQuery has a plugin for that ;)

Comment: So this is a duplicate of your own question from an hour ago? Or are you looking for a more general explanation of how JS arrays work?

Comment: Thank you for reply, just getting confused., cuz I have been told I need to create three arrays first then change the array every single time when you choose different item in the first dropdownlist.

Comment: You wouldn't change the array. You'd represent your data in some kind of array or object (multidimensional or not) and then when the selection is changed in the first drop-down you'd repopulate the second and third drop-downs by extracting the appropriate data out of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal objects:

```
var obj = {name : "Bob", nationality : "american", occasion : "often"};
```

You can access an update JS objects using `dot` notation or array notation:

```
obj["name"] = "Your Name Here";

obj.name = "Your Name Here";
```

You can push objects into and array to create a collection.  Multi-dimensional arrays are not necessary for the task you are describing.

Comment: What I have been told is I need to create three arrays, i am just really confused. Thank you all the same

Comment: You don't need 3 arrays.  You need one array and store objects created using the syntax above.  You could create a multi-dimensional array but it would be a lot more complex than needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different syntax I know for doing this in JavaScript.
These Examples assume a 2 by n size array.

1)

```
var categories = [[]];
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    categories[i] = new Array(value.cat_id, value.category_label);
    i++;
});
```

2)

```
var categories = [[]];
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    categories[i] = [
        [value.cat_id],
        [value.category_label]
    ];
    i++;
});
```

3)

```
var categories = [[]];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    categories.push([[value.cat_id],[value.category_label]]);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

please see this **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/LsmYt/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/LsmYt/1/

`.push` = http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Hope this helps, please lemme knw if I missed anything!

**code**

```
 var rambo=[];
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    rambo.push(['hulk ironman',i]);
    rambo.push(['Human nationality', i]);
    rambo.push(['Yay occassion', i]);
    $("#hulk").html(i);
}
alert(rambo.toSource());

$("#hulk").html(rambo.toSource());
```

Comment: Your string examples are completely mystifying. I think I like them.

Comment: @zetlen Thank-you! `:)` awe*&*someness of hulk :P innit I like your: http://diplomaticshark.com man nice one